# httpModule from base web application doesn't load in sub-project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httpmodule

VB.Net 2k5 Web Application

The base application has a web.config file with an httpModules section:

The sub-project compiles to the same bin folder as the base application, but I get this message:

> Parser Error Message: Could not load
> file or assembly
> 'Castle.MonoRail.Framework' or one of
> its dependencies. The system cannot
> find the file specified.
> (c:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config line
> 132)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 131:      [<]httpModules[>]
>
> Line 132:         [<]add name="monorail"
> type="Castle.MonoRail.Framework.EngineContextModule,
> Castle.MonoRail.Framework"/[>] --- Error here
>
> Line
> 133:         [<]add name="ScriptModule"
> type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule,
> System.Web.Extensions,
> Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/[>]
>
> Line 134:         [<]add name="active-record"
> type="Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.SessionScopeWebModule,
> Castle.ActiveRecord"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this. First, yes, the sub-project was building to the parent bin folder.

The issue was, I had both the parent and child folders set as applications in IIS. I made the child just a virtual folder, and the issue went away.

Why did this work? I tried shuffling around the HTTPModules, and found that the MS ScriptModule did not have the problem, but if I moved the ActiveRecord module first, it had the problem. I think that those modules have issues if they try to get loaded more than once. (Just a guess.)

Or it may have been that the security for the child, since it was an application, didn't allow loading assemblies from another application.

It is working now... on to other issues. Thanks.

Comment: Web.config are inherited all the way from machine root. So, yes, modules are inherited. but if an application can't see the assembly, it won't load and will throw an error. The assembly needs to be in a well known location - either GAC or the application bin folder. See my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a reference to the Castle.MonoRail.Framework in your web app project?

Answer (score 0):

is your sub-project configured to use the parent bin folder?

I'm assuming a layout like this:

```
 app
   /bin
   /subapp
     /bin
```

unless you've changed the probing path in the config, subapp won't see anything in the parent bin. That goes for anything defined in the web.config, eg config sections, httpmodules, etc that reference assemblies.

Comment: Hmm... how could I change the 'probing path' in the config? This may still help with some issues.